# Extending form validation in Codeigniter

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter

I have placed this class file called 'My_Form_validation.php' into 'application/core' and I have also tried placing it in 'application/libraries'.

In my controller I am using

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_postcode', 'Postcode', 'valid_postcode|trim|required|xss_clean');
```

This is whats in My_Form_validation.php - the actual logic is not in question here because I have a couple of options to actually validate the postcode. What I need help with is understanding why it is not loading or getting called!

My CI version is 
define('CI_VERSION', '2.0.2');

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Form validation for UK Postcodes
 * 
 * Check that its a valid postcode
 * @author James Mills <james@koodoocreative.co.uk>
 * @version 1.0
 * @package FriendsSavingMoney
 */

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        log_message('debug', '*** Hello from MY_Form_validation ***');
    }

    function valid_postcode($postcode)
    {

        /**
         *
         * UK Postcode validation expression from Wikipedia
         * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom
         *
         * Note: Remember to strtoupper() your postcode before inserting into database!
         *
         */

        $pattern = "/^(GIR 0AA)|(((A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRSTX]?|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]?|F[KY]|G[LUY]?|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]?|M[EKL]?|N[EGNPRW]?|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKLMNOPRSTY]?|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)[1-9]?[0-9]|((E|N|NW|SE|SW|W)1|EC[1-4]|WC[12])[A-HJKMNPR-Y]|(SW|W)([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])|EC[1-9][0-9]) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$/";


        if (preg_match($pattern, strtoupper($postcode)))
    {
            return TRUE;
        } 
        else
        {
            $this->set_message('valid_postcode', 'Please enter a valid postcode');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sanity checks: 1) file is `application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`, 2) `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';`, 3) Your config log threshold will output your debug message (and file permissions allow it)

Comment: No clue.  I'd have to shotgun debug it with all kinds of `var_dump()` and `die()` calls...

Comment: Have you tried editing the language/english/form_validation_lang.php file, instead of setting the message inside the method? Like so: `$lang['valid_postcode'] =  "Please enter a valid postcode";`

Comment: Should be MY_ not My_ . Looks like you're using the latter based on your question making reference to the contents of My_Form_validation.php

Comment: I'm having the same problem as this, I placed the file correctly, the filename is correct. I load the library in my controller. Everything is set right. But the methods in my custom validation is not being loaded. I get this message "Unable to find validation rule: is_Fieldunique". Why is that so?

Comment: @James Mills: where you able to figure out, how to fix it?

Answer (score 18):

Because you're extending a CodeIgniter library and not a core component, you want to place that in `application/libraries` (not `application/core`).

And of course, don't forget to load the `Form_validation` library within your controller code.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Other things to check:

- Filename case sensitivity (`MY_Form_validation.php` loads while `My_Form_validation.php` won't)
- Class name case sensitivity (class `MY_Form_validation` extends `CI_Form_validation`)

Reference material:

- [Extending Core Classes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html)
- [Extending Native Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: I tried all different types of capitalizations in the `MY_Form_validation` file and file name but none of them worked. Might there be a change depending on the version of CI one is using?

Comment: @timpeterson: I did the same thing. Were you able to figure out a solution to this?

Comment: I've had endless nightmares trying to get this to work properly. My file and class were both named `My_form_validation` instead of `MY_Form_validation`. I'm kicking myself now

Answer (score 12):

You have to add $rules on your __construct method and also pass this to parent constructor

eg:

```
function __construct($rules = array())
{
    parent::__construct($rules);
}
```

Look at Form_validation and provide same variables.

Comment: ialbescu, FTW. Not only does this make sense, it also works. I can't believe I overlooked passing the rules array. Nicely done. +1