# CodeIgniter load custom form_validation config file

Tags: codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.3, and HMVC by Wiredesignz.

How can I include a custom form_validation configuration file in the module's folder (in application/modules/user/config/form_validation.php) as opposed to the central config folder (application/config/form_validation.php)?

**Edit** I have accepted Salvador's answer, due to his suggestion in the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why in config?

There is a better way, you can use it in application/libaries/MY_form_validation.php

There you can safely modify the form_validation class o add new features.

Check [this](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/207257/#978612) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160610/extending-form-validation-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Because I want my modules to be self-contained. If someone would like to not use the current user module, they can simply drop in their own user module and delete the default one.

Comment: modules/user is as a different application? like modules/user1 -- modules/user2 .... If it's that the case you can use a different config/libraries... per app, and all the applications can share the core of codeigniter.

Comment: No, just a different module for the main app. The modules I write depend on the base code contained in the app, but the modules extend the functions provided.

Comment: Mmm maybe you can use hooks and a special file you create in config. The user can use the config file to specify the validators to use, and then you in the hooks modify the behaviour of the validator based in the values of the config file.

Comment: Hi Salvador, thanks for the comment. I have decided, however, to go with specifying the validation rules in the controller function. It was just too much to change for too little benefit.

Comment: Hi Salvador. I opted for the suggestion in your comment about using a hook to do this task, hence I am accepting your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
  $config=[
    'add_article_rules'  => [
           [
            'field' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Article Title',
            'rules' => 'required|alpha'
           ],
           [
            'field'=>'body',
            'label'=>'Article Body',
            'rules'=>'required',

           ]
          ],
    'admin_login' =>  [
          [
           'field'=> 'username',
           'label'=> 'User Name',
           'rules'=> 'required|alpha|trim',
          ],
          [
           'field'=>'password',
           'label'=>'password',
           'rules'=>'required',
          ]

         ]


    ];
  ?>
```