# How to create multiple Codeigniter form validation classes

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently I'm extending `MY_Form_validation.php` to execute my all validation callbacks. My problem is, Is there any way to separate the Form validation callbacks. Like

```
class User_Form_Validation extends CI_Form_validation{}

class Product_Form_Validation extends CI_Form_validation{}
```

My idea is, insted of putting all callbacks into one file, to separate it

Comment: Seems like it should work as long as you follow rules, for example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160610/extending-form-validation-in-codeigniter.  What happens when you try to do this?

Comment: Seems like it would have taken less time to just try this, than it did to write the question.