# creating custom callback validation rule in codeigniter 2.x

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

how can I create custom validation rule in codeigniter 2.x which can be commonly used throughout application?

I know we can create callback functions in controller, which can then be used in validation rule as -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_dob', 'Date of Birth', 'required|callback_validDate|callback_validAge');
```

And now we can create validation function in controller as -

```
public function validDate($date) {
     $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y', $date);
     if ($d && $d->format('d-M-Y') == $date)
          return TRUE;

     $this->form_validation->set_message('validDate', ' %s is not in correct date format');
     return FALSE;
}
```

But there is a limitation. I can use this method only inside that particular controller. This function can't be used for other controllers. I will have to write the same code again.

For this I tried creating helper file with the given validation function, but again no luck.

So how can I use validation function many times, created once at a common file in codeigniter ?

Comment: You can use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: Also, you can try to inherit `CI_Form_validation` and implement your validation methods, so they can be used as rules. Or, you can try to import `CI_Form_validation` from CodeIgniter 3 which supports [callable rules](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule)

Comment: there is a subject, which can give you a clue on extending validation lib with your own rules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160610/extending-form-validation-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too faced the same problem. So I came across a solution for creating validation function, common all around the controller.

Create a file `MY_Form_validation.php` in the directory `/application/libraries/` with following code -

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    protected $CI;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
    }

    function validDate($date) {
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('validDate', ' %s is not in correct date format');

        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y', $date);
        if ($d && $d->format('d-M-Y') == $date)
            return TRUE;

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now in your controller, you can use the function name as new rule as -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_dob', 'Date of Birth', 'required|validDate|validAge');
```

And if required you can load library in constructor of controller as -

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

For further information you can refer to the link -https://arjunphp.com/custom-validation-rules-codeigniter/